# How to parse messages received through pipe

Tags: c++, winapi

I created my pipe server which it create a instance of
pipe by using the function ConnectNamedPipe.
after that I read from the pipe and save the data into buffer.
I have not created my client yet but I have to do some operations.

My client has to write to the pipe 2 things:
1 -  The operation that the server will does - Subtract, Multiply, Addition, Division(I'm trying to implement kind of calculator)
2 - 2 numbers that the server will calculate

My server has to read from the pipe those operations and the 2 numbers 
and print the result on the screen.

So, my question is that, how can I parse those 2 operations that the client wrote?

My server working fine but i have problem with parsing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE createPipe;
    BOOL Connect;
    BOOL Read;
    int buffer[100];
    DWORD numBytesRead;

    //Create Pipe
    createPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        L"\\\\.\\pipe\\StackOverflow",
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        1024,
        1024,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL);

    //Check for failure
    if(createPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        cout<<"Failed to create a pipe! "<<endl;
    }

    //Create instance of the pipe
    Connect = ConnectNamedPipe(
        createPipe,
        NULL);

    //Check for failure
    if(!(Connect)){
        cout<<"Failed to connect to the pipe"<<endl;
        CloseHandle(createPipe);
    }

    //Read bytes from the buffer
    Read = ReadFile(
            createPipe, 
            buffer,
            99 * sizeof(buffer),
            &numBytesRead,
            NULL);

    //check for failure
    if(!(Read)){
        cout<<"Failed to read from the pipe"<<endl;
        CloseHandle(createPipe);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thx

Comment: I wish..I wanna do this coz it helps me improving my programming skills

Comment: OK. Your title says the problem is with passing the data through the pipes. So you send the data with the client but it doesn't reach the server, correct?

Comment: My problem is that i dont know how to parse message which sent from the client to the server

Comment: Then edit your title and question to make it clear what your problem actually is. Right now its misleading and confusing, and I don't think anyone will be able to answer it.

Comment: How you parse it depends on how you format it and package it to send over the the pipe, whether it's delimited, fixed length, counted, etc. You'll need to show us sending code too.

Answer (score 0):

You should research serialization - how you encode and decode the pipe data should be encapsulated. You have a Calculation object that has two Operand elements (numbers) and an Operation (enumeration maybe?) - then the problem becomes how do you serialize (send) and deserialize (receiver) that object, independent of the pipe I/O.

Check out Boost.Serialization for concepts - boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html